# LinqToSql query to datatable invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hello here's a linqtosql query that create DataTables :

```
private void GetStock()
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {

            #region ARTICLES
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("FICHES_ARTICLES");
            var article = from a in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES
                      where a.ART_SITE == 7
                      select new
                      {
                          a.ART_CODE,
                          a.ART_SITE,
                          a.ART_LIBELLE1,
                          a.ART_LIBELLE2,
                          a.ART_SIGNEQ,
                          a.ART_EAN13,
                          a.ART_DLUO,
                          a.ART_RESSUAGE,
                          a.EMB_CODE
                      };
            DataColumn dc1 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_CODE", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc2 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_SITE", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc3 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_LIBELLE1", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc4 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_LIBELLE2", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc5 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_SIGNEQ", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc6 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_EAN13", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc7 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_DLUO", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc8 = dt.Columns.Add("ART_RESSUAGE", typeof(double));
            DataColumn dc9 = dt.Columns.Add("EMB_CODE", typeof(string));
            DataRow dw;
            foreach (var item in article)
            {
                dw = dt.NewRow();
                dw["ART_CODE"] = item.ART_CODE;
                dw["ART_SITE"] = item.ART_SITE;
                dw["ART_LIBELLE1"] = item.ART_LIBELLE1;
                dw["ART_LIBELLE2"] = item.ART_LIBELLE2;
                dw["ART_SIGNEQ"] = item.ART_SIGNEQ;
                dw["ART_EAN13"] = item.ART_EAN13;
                dw["ART_DLUO"] = item.ART_DLUO;
                dw["ART_RESSUAGE"] = item.ART_RESSUAGE;
                dw["EMB_CODE"] = item.EMB_CODE;
                dt.Rows.Add(dw);
            }
            #endregion

            #region ART_PARAM
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("ART_PARAM");
            var param = from p in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES
                        where p.ART_SITE == 7
                        orderby p.ART_LIBELLE1
                        select new
                        {
                            p.ART_CODE,
                            p.ART_SITE,
                            p.ART_LIBELLE1
                        };
            DataColumn dc10 = dt1.Columns.Add("ART_CODE", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc11 = dt1.Columns.Add("ART_SITE", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc12 = dt1.Columns.Add("ART_LIBELLE1", typeof(string));
            DataRow dw1;
            foreach (var c in param)
            {
                dw1 = dt1.NewRow();
                dw1["ART_CODE"] = c.ART_CODE;
                dw1["ART_SITE"] = c.ART_SITE;
                dw1["ART_LIBELLE1"] = c.ART_LIBELLE1;
                dt1.Rows.Add(dw1);
            }
            #endregion

            #region ENTREES_STOCKS
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("ENTREES_STOCKS");

            var ent = from e in dc.ENTREES_STOCKS
                      select new
                      {
                          e.ID,
                          e.ART_CODE,
                          e.ENTSTK_DTENTREE,
                          e.ENTSTK_PICKING,
                          e.ENTSTK_LOT,
                          e.ENTSTK_PNET,
                          e.ENTSTK_NBU,
                          e.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM,
                          e.ENTSTK_USER
                      };
            DataColumn dc13 = dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc14 = dt2.Columns.Add("ART_CODE", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc15 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_DTENTREE", typeof(DateTime));
            DataColumn dc16 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_PICKING", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc17 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_LOT", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc18 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_PNET", typeof(float));
            DataColumn dc19 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_NBU", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dc20 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_DATE_DEM", typeof(DateTime));
            DataColumn dc21 = dt2.Columns.Add("ENTSTK_USER", typeof(string));
            DataRow dw2;
            foreach (var c in ent)
            {
                dw2 = dt2.NewRow();
                dw2["ID"] = c.ID;
                dw2["ART_CODE"] = c.ART_CODE;
                dw2["ENTSTK_DTENTREE"] = c.ENTSTK_DTENTREE;
                dw2["ENTSTK_PICKING"] = c.ENTSTK_PICKING;
                dw2["ENTSTK_LOT"] = c.ENTSTK_LOT;
                dw2["ENTSTK_PNET"] = c.ENTSTK_PNET;
                dw2["ENTSTK_NBU"] = c.ENTSTK_NBU;
                //dw2["ENTSTK_DATE_DEM"] = c.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM;
                if (dw2["ENTSTK_DATE_DEM"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dw2["ENTSTK_DATE_DEM"] = c.ENTSTK_DATE_DEM;
                }
                dw2["ENTSTK_USER"] = c.ENTSTK_USER;
                dt2.Rows.Add(dw2);
            }
            #endregion

            #region DataSet
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
            #endregion

            #region Create Crystal Report
            string reportPath = DocNameTB.Text;
            ReportDocument cr = new ReportDocument();
            cr.Load(reportPath);
            cr.SetDataSource(ds);
            Cr_Viewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cr;
            #endregion

        }
    }
```

in the first region "ARTICLES" i'm getting an error at the line
"foreach(var item in article)" : invalid cast exception
I don(t understand why ??
The thing is that this code is similar (and work perfectly) for every other Regions...

[image: Error Message]

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: which line *exactly* is failing; note that the debugger isn't always accurate - for example, is it `dw["ART_CODE"] = item.ART_CODE;` ? but more fundamentally: *why* are you pushing perfectly good classes into data-tables? (inquiring minds would love to know...)

Comment: I would suggest to comment out all value assignments except the first inside the loop. then run it. If it works take the next line back into code and try again....until you find the line that is actually responsible for the wrong datatype

Comment: Is ART_SITE a number of a string?  I think this line is the issue : where a.ART_SITE == 7

Comment: @jdweng if it would be a string then OP would get a compile error and not a runtime error by exception

Comment: No.  The compile does not know type in a datatable column.

Comment: @jdweng But `a` is not a `DataTable`.

Comment: The `foreach` can't cause a cast exception. Can you show the class type for `dc.FICHES_ARTICLES`?

Comment: You do not understand how Linq and Entity works.  The foreach is performing a query of the database.

Comment: @jdweng Was that aimed at me? Because I can assure you, I know _exactly_ how it works (though I have been known to overlook something). Can you please point out where `DataTable` is involved in the LINQ or the `foreach`?

Comment: I should of said the data mapping that Entity was using for the database.   article is a list of rows in the database (from table dc.FICHES_ARTICLES) and ART_SITE is numeric and the column in the database must also be numeric.  It is possible the column contains null in the database so you may have a cast issue going from null to int.

Comment: @jdweng "The compile does not know type in a datatable column" when using linq2sql a model is created of each table, with all corresponding types. So the compiler does know the data types from this model classes.

Comment: I never said the compiler would detect the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using an extension method to automate this, which will also eliminate (data) typing issues:

```
public static IEnumerableExt {
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        if (rows.Any()) {
            var memberInfos = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOrFields();
            foreach (var info in memberInfos)
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.GetMemberType()));

            foreach (var r in rows)
                dt.Rows.Add(memberInfos.Select(i => i.GetValue(r)).ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```